# pyScss installation fails

Tags: python, pip

Starting today June 8, I'm seeing this error when trying to install pyScss with pip:

```
$ pip install "pyScss>=1.1.5"
Downloading/unpacking pyScss>=1.1.5
  Downloading pyScss-1.2.0.post3.tar.gz (94kB): 94kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/venv/build/pyScss/setup.py) egg_info for package pyScss
    no previously-included directories found matching 'documentation/_build'
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    six: module references __path__

    Installed /private/tmp/venv/build/pyScss/six-1.7.0-py2.7.egg
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/venv/build/pyScss/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from scss.scss_meta import PROJECT, URL, VERSION, AUTHOR, AUTHOR_EMAIL, LICENSE, DOWNLOAD_URL
      File "scss/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
        from scss.functions import ALL_BUILTINS_LIBRARY
      File "scss/functions/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from scss.functions.core import CORE_LIBRARY
      File "scss/functions/core.py", line 11, in <module>
        from six.moves import xrange
      File "/var/folders/v6/mg7h8rjd4bbf51n7dm1j00jc0000gn/T/easy_install-pX0iRW/six-1.7.0/six.py", line 187, in load_module
        return sys.modules[fullname]
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modules'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    no previously-included directories found matching 'documentation/_build'

zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...

six: module references __path__



Installed /private/tmp/venv/build/pyScss/six-1.7.0-py2.7.egg

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/tmp/venv/build/pyScss/setup.py", line 13, in <module>

    from scss.scss_meta import PROJECT, URL, VERSION, AUTHOR, AUTHOR_EMAIL, LICENSE, DOWNLOAD_URL

  File "scss/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>

    from scss.functions import ALL_BUILTINS_LIBRARY

  File "scss/functions/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>

from scss.functions.core import CORE_LIBRARY

  File "scss/functions/core.py", line 11, in <module>

    from six.moves import xrange

  File "/var/folders/v6/mg7h8rjd4bbf51n7dm1j00jc0000gn/T/easy_install-pX0iRW/six-1.7.0/six.py", line 187, in load_module

    return sys.modules[fullname]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modules'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
```

This appears to be triggered by today's release of Six 1.7.0 (same installs worked before). It seems like six is used during the `setup.py egg_info` phase of the pyScss install. Triggering a "private" six install that fails.

Notes:

Installing six in a separate pip command prior to installing pyScss resolves this, but

- a requirements file with both `six==1.6.1` and `pyScss` will fail in the same way.
- So will a requirements file with `six==1.7.0` and `pyScss`.

Any idea how to install pyScss from a requirements file without requiring a separate `pip install six` step?

Comment: The workaround using two separate pip commands seems to only work with older pip (1.1), and not with the newer 1.5.4 or 1.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

The problem described here was reported as an issue with Six:

https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/issue/71/six-17-causes-installing-some-packages-to#comment-10609667

And resolved in six version 1.7.1.
An even newer 1.7.2 was also released solving another pip install issue.